# Saving a table in VisualBasic 2010 to a .txt file

Tags: vb.net

I am looking to get the table that is generated at the end of the program below have the option to be saved into a .txt so that it can be looked back to at a later date but am struggling to get this to happen.

```
    Module Module1
    Dim kTick As Integer
    Dim kName(64) As String
    Dim kHours(64) As Integer
    Dim kHoursPay(64) As Integer
    Dim kGross(64) As Integer
    Dim kTax As Integer = 20
    Dim kNet(64) As Integer
    Dim kTotal As Integer
    Dim kAverage As Integer
    Sub Main()
        'Assigning kTick (Number of employee's)
        Assign()
        'Imputting the data
        Entry()
        'Calculating kGross, kTax, kNet and kTotal
        Print()
    End Sub
    Sub Assign()
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the total amount of employee's:")
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
        kTick = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Clear()
    End Sub
    Sub Entry()
        For kCounter = 1 To kTick
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkGray
            Console.WriteLine("Employee " & kCounter)
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the employee name below:")
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
            kName(kCounter) = Console.ReadLine()
            Do
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the employees total hours worked below:")
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
                kHours(kCounter) = Console.ReadLine()
            Loop Until kHours(kCounter) >= 0 And kHours(kCounter) <= 60
            Do
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the employees Hourly Pay below:")
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
                kHoursPay(kCounter) = Console.ReadLine()
            Loop Until kHoursPay(kCounter) >= 6 And kHoursPay(kCounter) <= 250
            Console.Clear()
        Next
    End Sub
    Sub Print()
        For kCounter = 1 To kTick
            kGross(kCounter) = kHours(kCounter) * kHoursPay(kCounter)
        Next
        For kCounter = 1 To kTick
            kNet(kCounter) = (kGross(kCounter) / 10) * 8
        Next
        For kCounter = 1 To kTick
            kTotal = kTotal + kHours(kCounter)
        Next
        kAverage = kTotal / kTick
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray
        Console.WriteLine("Name" & vbTab & "Hours" & vbTab & "Hourly Rate" & vbTab & "Gross Pay" & vbTab & "Tax" & vbTab & "Net Pay")
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
        For kCounter = 1 To kTick
            Console.WriteLine(kName(kCounter) & vbTab & kHours(kCounter) & vbTab & "£" & kHoursPay(kCounter) & vbTab & vbTab & "£" & kGross(kCounter) & vbTab & vbTab & kTax & "%" & vbTab & "£" & kNet(kCounter))
        Next
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray
        Console.WriteLine("Total hours worked: " & kTotal)
        Console.WriteLine("Total average hours worked: " & kAverage)
        Console.WriteLine("Total number of employees: " & kTick)
        Console.ReadLine()
        Save()
    End Sub
    Sub Save()

    End Sub
End Module
```

I am trying to get the code in the Save subroutine any help will be appreciated!

Thanks Kai

Answer (score 1):

One note: you should not `Save` from `Print` since both are unrelated by nature. So you may want to print without saving or save without printing to the console.

A simple approach is using the `File` class, for example by using [`File.WriteAllText(path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375.aspx) or [`File.WriteAllLines(path)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693.aspx). Therefore you need to store the text you want to output(to the console and the file) somewhere. For example in a `List(Of String)` variable.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.aspx) class. It has `Write` and `WriteLine` methods that can help you. It works in a same way as `Console.WriteLine` you are using.